# Impossible to save diagram generated by PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I want to save my diagram UML generated by PhpStorm into my project directory but when I select any directory I have this error :

**Can't save diagram to C:\location......\Export.uml**

This error appear for any directory and there is nothing error IDE PhpStorm in Event log. I have nothing other log.

My environment is :

- *Windows 7 x64*
- *PhpStorm 10.0.3*
- *Project Symfony2*

Strange behaviour isn't it ? Have you an idea ?

Comment: **1)** Check your `idea.log` for possible details (`Help | Show Log in...`) **2)** These kind of "bug in IDE" questions better ask at JB support site: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367219-PhpStorm